# Parse text from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

i have string in textbox:

```
  `New-Value = 12,34   -- Old-Values: 12,31,`
```

what i'd like to do is to get Old-Value so "12,31,"

How can i get from this textbox this specific information do this? So value is between ":" and ","

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string oldPointer = "Old-Values: ";
var text = "New-Value = 12,34   -- Old-Values: 12,31,";
var old = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(oldPointer) + oldPointer.Length).TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

> Regex.Match("New-Value = 12,34   -- Old-Values: 12,31,",@"\:(.+)\,").Groups[1].Value.Trim()

Answer (score 0):

Not  very clear if this is a fixed (static) format of your string, but by the way:

A simple solution could be:

```
string str = "New-Value = 12,34   -- Old-Values: 12,31,"; 
str.Substring(str.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

More complex one should involve `Regular expressions`, like an answer of L.B or others if any.